# Update your web.config to specify a different version?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-webpages

This is my error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Specified Web Pages version "3.0.0.0" could not be found. Update your web.config to specify a different version. Current version: "2.0.0.0".
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Specified Web Pages version "3.0.0.0" could not be found. Update your web.config to specify a different version. Current version: "2.0.0.0".

And this is how my web config looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
  <appSettings>
<add key="GoogleAnalytics:PropertyID" value="" />
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
 </system.web>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.WebPages.WebPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Configuration" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <location path="crossdomain.xml">
  <system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clear />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/x-cross-domain-policy" />
  </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I already change version. Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this just installing ASP:NET MVC and EntityFramework using NuGet packages